# rspamd redis sentinel time out

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel, rspamd

Since some time we are running rspamd and redis (and sentinel) with a separate DB for most modules. Data seems to be written to the databases but for some reason we get errors like "cannot get masters data from Redis Sentinel 10.11.12.1:26379: timeout while connecting the server". We also get this error for the slaves. The rspamd log shows that it gets the list of masters and slaves..

Telnet to the IP and port works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Read through the source code and just had to add timeout = 5.0; to the config file(s)